# .NET Cross platform cache dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, cache-dependency

What would one recommend as a cross platform cache dependency?

Our application may use multiple database platforms (e.g. MSSQL and MySQL) so this rules out Sql Cache Dependency.

I had thought about using a file cache dependency and just touching the file when my data changes. However, this is only really of any benefit if I can use the same file cache dependency with output caching in ASP.NET MVC (the OutputCache attribute only has an option for SqlDependency).

Many thanks,
Ben

[Update]
We aim to use the built in caching features of .NET (System.Runtime.Caching) not any external cache providers (AppFabric, Memcached etc.)

Comment: I was wondering if you found an answer for this.

Comment: did you found a way to use MySql cache dependency ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the caching functionality in Windows [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc645013.aspx). Comes with lots of behaviour for handling cache dependencies and invalidation.

Comment: thanks for the info. However, we do not intend to use an external cache provider. I've updated my question to this effect.